# Is there a specific design pattern for managing YAML aliases in large files?

Tags: design-patterns, yaml, data-modeling, data-files

I have a big YAML file that stores test cases for my app. It uses a lot of anchors and alias to share parts among test cases. It was initially ok to manage, but it now seems to have outgrown from what we can easily edit.

It is now really difficult to see where each keys refers to or what are the actual values we will see after it gets parsed. So my question is if there is any handy way to look at how YAML will be parsed associated with where each value comes from.

For instance, when my YAML is like so:

```
1: test_case_1: &base_case
2:   case_component_a: 'foo'
3:   case_component_b: 'bar'
4: test_case_expectation_1: &base_expectation
5:   expectation_component_a: 'foo_foo'
6:   expectation_component_b: 'bar_bar'
7: test_case_set_1:
8:   <<: *base_case
9:   <<: *base_expectation
```

is there any handy way to view this in something like the following way?

```
test_case_set_1: 
  case_component_a: 'foo'  {from &base_case line:2}
  case_component_b: 'bar'  {from &base_case line:3}
  expectation_component_a: 'foo_foo'  {from &base_expectation line:5}
  expectation_component_b: 'bar_bar'  {from &base_expectation line:6}
```

What is the best practice for creating maintainable, extensible and readable files when there are several hundred or more data records? Is there any guidance in the YAML specification?